# How do i consume the w3schools tempCnvertor webservice from the wsdl with netbeans?

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservices-client

I have been trying to consume the w3schools tempConvertor webservice from

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

it gives me this warning messages just before generating the client classes

> parsing WSDL...
>
> [WARNING] SOAP port "TempConvertSoap12": uses a non-standard SOAP 1.2
>   binding.   line 147 of
>   file:/C:/Users/Bigesta/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaebServiceDemo/xml-resources/web-service-references/tempconvert/wsdl/www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx.wsdl
>
> [WARNING] Port "TempConvertHttpPost" is not a SOAP port, it has no
>   soap:address   line 150 of
>   file:/C:/Users/Bigesta/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaebServiceDemo/xml-resources/web-service-references/tempconvert/wsdl/www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx.wsdl
>
> [WARNING] port "TempConvertHttpPost": not a standard SOAP port. The
>   generated artifacts may not work with JAX-WS runtime.   line 150 of
>   file:/C:/Users/Bigesta/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaebServiceDemo/xml-resources/web-service-references/tempconvert/wsdl/www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx.wsdl
>
> Generating code...
>
> https\www_w3schools_com\xml\CelsiusToFahrenheit.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\FahrenheitToCelsius.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\ObjectFactory.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\TempConvert.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\TempConvertHttpPost.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\TempConvertSoap.java
>   https\www_w3schools_com\xml\package-info.java Copying 9 files to
>   C:\Users\Bigesta\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaebServiceDemo\build\generated-sources\jax-ws
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

When ever i try to call the service i get this exceptions

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server
>   sent HTTP status code 301: Moved Permanently  at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:310)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:259)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.fahrenheitToCelsius(Unknown Source)   at
>   javaebservicedemo.JavaebServiceDemo.fahrenheitToCelsius(JavaebServiceDemo.java:26)
>     at
>   javaebservicedemo.JavaebServiceDemo.main(JavaebServiceDemo.java:19)

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

When the WSDL is parsed the warnings are stating that the WSDL is not following SOAP 1.2 binding conventions in particular: SOAP port has no soap:address. This WSDL maybe trying to support both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2

The response you are getting is [301: Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) which is trying to redirect you.

There is an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=FahrenheitToCelsius

However, when I use the post example I get a 500 server error which isn't a good sign.

To save time I recommend using a tool like SOAPUI to test and validate the service is working before creating your demo. You could try and use a different service such as http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Another simple ws that works at the time of writing: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl